# Code inside .ajaxStop repeats continuosly

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

What I want is to run a function only when all the content of a specific div is loaded and all the ajax requests related to that div are completed. So I have this piece of code:

```
$('#calendar-cont').ajaxStop(function() {
       getEventsData();// a function that contains some ajax requests

});
```

The problem is that the `getEventsData()` contains some other ajax requests and, for a reason that I don't understand (but I think is related to the ajax requests inside the `getEventsData()`) this function is run over and over again. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxStop` is not specific to a certain element, so `ajaxStop` will be called after the ajax request inside `getEventsData()` has finished, so you have an infinite loop.